# Creating Multi-level pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, hierarchical-data

I am trying to create a hierarchical dataframe based on a dataframe that I have. I have managed to create a multi index dataframe as follows:

[Image of dataframe structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeOmI.png)

So my dataframe index is the following:

```
MultiIndex([('x',    'yellow'),
            ('x',      'blue'),
            ('x',     'green'),
            ('x',     'white'),
            ('x',     'ind10'),
            ('x',       'red'),
            ('x', 'turquoise'),
            ('x',     'black'),
            ('x',    'purple'),
            ('x',    'orange'),
            ('x',     'ind11'),
            ('y',    'yellow'),
            ('y',      'blue'),
            ('y',     'green'),
            ('y',     'white'),
            ('y',     'ind10'),
            ('y',       'red'),
            ('y', 'turquoise'),
            ('y',     'black'),
            ('y',    'purple'),
            ('y',    'orange'),
            ('y',     'ind11')],
           )
```

Now I am trying to convert this into something with the following structure:

```
yellow  x   ........
        y   ........
orange  x   ........
        y   ........
.
.
.
ind11   x   ........
        y   ........
```

But I can't seem to do this. I have tried various forms of `pd.MultiIndex.from_frame` but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html):

```
df1 = mux.to_frame(index=False)

df1 = df.columns.to_frame(index=False)
```

Or maybe:

```
df2 = df.T
```